# Build WebServices layer on top of Drupal

Tags: web-services, drupal, layer

Can someone tell me what's the best way to build a Web Services layer on top of Drupal?

Comment: See http://drupal.org/project/services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use something that already exists: http://drupal.org/project/services
If it's not enough, you can create your own module which use Services module.

It would be quick and clean :-)